# setSelectionRange is not a function

Tags: javascript, selection

This seems so simple, but it's not working:

```js
document.getElementById('test').setSelectionRange(3,3)
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the 'test' element needs to be an `<input/>` element. Try revising your HTML as follows:

```
<input id="test" />
```

Also consider the following changes to your javascript. With these updates to your code, your javascript should work as expected when there is enough text in your input field. For example, consider this code for selecting "world" in "hello world":

```js
const input = document.getElementById('test');
input.focus();
input.setSelectionRange(6,11);
```

```html
<input id="test" value="hello world" />
```

For more information, [see the MDN docs for `setSelectionRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)

Comment: so what do if we want it for <div> or <p>?

Comment: @AnilPBabu I'm not sure I follow - can you please give me detail on what you mean?

Comment: you said 'This is because the 'test' element needs to be an <input/> element.'. But the question was for <div>. Is there any way to apply setSelectionRange for <div>

Comment: I'm not aware of a way for a `<div>` sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="test" value="hello world" />

var InputElement = $('test')[0] as HTMLInputElement;
InputElement.setSelectionRange(3, 3);
```

Comment: Think we need to get the element as an array indexed one $('test')[0] and then call the setSelectionRange(3, 3). Example: $('test')[0].setSelectionRange(3, 3);

Answer (score 0):

To make this on `<div>` you should make it editable:

`<div id="test" contenteditable="true">test</div>`